# How to use equalizer on ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, equalizer

I want to change the frequency of my videos. I think I can do this with ffmpeg equalizer but i couldn't find any documents about that. My video's name is video1.mp4

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly? What do you mean by, "change the frequency of my videos"?

Comment: I want to add some noise and change octave, slope, Q-Factor, Hz. I have to try all of them one by one. I am trying something on my videos so i don't know which one is suitable for my project.

Comment: Why couldn't you find documentation about it? [The `equalizer` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#equalizer) is fairly well documented. What have you already tried?

Comment: There is no examples about that and i don't know how to write the code with those information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would strongly encourage you to [read the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1). Even if there is no example, there is a specific description of how filters are defined on the command line.

> A filter is represented by a string of the form: `filter_name=arguments` (…)
>
> `arguments` is a string which contains the parameters used to initialize the filter instance
>
> - A `:`-separated list of `key=value` pairs.
> - …

So, [the `equalizer` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#equalizer) takes these (required) arguments:

- `f` – central frequency in Hz
- `width_type` – for defining the bandwidth, can be one of `h` (Hz), `q` (Q), `o` (octave) or `s` (slope).
- `w` – the value of the chosen bandwidth
- `g` – the gain

Now let's put that all together. For example, you can use this command to attenuate 10 dB at 1000 Hz with a bandwidth of 200 Hz:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "equalizer=f=1000:width_type=h:width=200:g=-10" output.wav
```

Or, for equalizing 2 octaves from 440 Hz (i.e., 220–880 Hz), with a gain of 5 dB (beware of clipping!):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "equalizer=f=440:width_type=o:width=2:g=5" output.wav
```

And if you want to combine these two, separate them by a `,`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "equalizer=f=440:width_type=o:width=2:g=5,equalizer=f=1000:width_type=h:width=200:g=-10" output.wav
```

Comment: I sent a patch to include some examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you @slhck .These examples helped me a lot. I have another question about audio filters on ffmpeg. Is the time stretching possible on ffmpeg? This [link](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/after-effects/using/time-stretching-time-remapping.html#time_stretch_a_layer) explains what is time-stretch.

Comment: See [Tool to bulk speed up/convert an audio file](http://superuser.com/questions/519649/tool-to-bulk-speed-up-convert-an-audio-file)